# Please blacklist the [jasper] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blocklist-request

The [jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper) tag is like a Phoenix bird. A long time ago it was used for marking:

- problems with Tomcat (*org.jasper* package)
- posts about JasperReports

It was a hard task to processing this mixed queue.

The main tag for questions on *JasperReports* is [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports)

Comment: There are no [jasper] questions that I can see.

Comment: I've just finished of retarging post. The same situation was yesterday. It is endless process

Comment: So, yours isn't a burnination request, but a blacklist one.

Comment: You have my vote, I know how much effort you do keeping jasper-reports in shape.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thank you, Petter. It is our common pain :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Proposed text for the blacklist box:

> [jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper) is an ambiguous tag and has been blacklisted. You may use one of the following:
>
> - [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) for question related to the Java reporting framework.
> - [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomcat) for question related to the Tomcats JSP Parser

For the last one I didn't find a more specific tag.

Comment: `for question related to the Java reporting server/libraries.` - for questions related to the JasperReports framework. We have another tag for JR Server  and so on

Comment: @AlexK Then, um, what's the bounds of the framework?

Comment: The questions can be about: Java API, about GUI designers, about JR Server, about designing templates, about constructing datasources/queries/expressions. That it is all about JasperReports framework

Comment: There's also a glassfish-jasper (the fork of jasper in the glassfish project)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt are people confusing [jasper] tag with that?

Comment: I've cleaned up a few within the scope of the [jetty] tag.  Jetty has support for both the tomcat-jasper, and the glassfish-jasper fork (different libs, different support levels, wildly different set of bugs, etc..)